# How do I write a macro in Komodo Edit IDE?

Tags: python, komodo

I need to have a macro run when I save a file.  I have the code for the file save, i just don't know the code to wrap round it for triggering it when saving.

I think komodo edit is written in Python, so assuming if anyone knows the code for the following in Python it would work:

```
onFileSave{

//do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the [ActiveState macro](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/macros.html) pages or [macro api](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/macroapi.html) pages.

Macros can be done in python or javascript. Recording a macro creates a javascript macro.  You can also create the macro by right clicking on the toolbox (right) panel.

**Once a macro is created, visit the "Triggers" tab from the "Properties" menu item (right clicking on the macro).**

SO makes nice one stop shopping but I've found the ActiveState developers to be very responsive and helpful on the [ActiveState support forums](http://support.activestate.com/forums/).

Comment: ahh that's brilliant thank you.  I didn't know about the right clicking part, I must have missed that when I read the docs earlier.  I'll try it out when I'm back and work tomorrow and mark you as correct.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I don't suppose you know how I can disable the command output window from popping up?  It's an extension I installed that I initialise with the macro.  However it outputs to the command window which then pops up as a tab at the bottom of the screen which is annoying.  I don't want to know it's done it's thing.

Comment: its ok, one of the options in the extension is disable command outputs.